# Adding the value from my third party API to my the state of the account balance

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently working on a project that uses a third party API with stock exchange information from https://finnhub.io/login I have currently got the quote(price) information to render in state, but I want to access the current price and have a buy function that effects the state of the account balance and adds 1 to the stockShares each time the buy button is clicked. I have two models in my database resources and a User i want add  the stock information to the

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import * as ReactBootStrap from "react-bootstrap"






export default class Home extends Component {
    state = {


        symbol: {
            enteredSymbol: ' ',

        },

        user: {
            stockShares: 0,
            accountBalance: 1000000,
        }

}

// getting user information
getUserInfo = () =>{
    axios.get('/api/user').then((response)=>{
        this.setState({
            user : response.data.accountBalance
        })
    })
}




//functions for stock api calls
    changeInput = (event) =>{
        const newSymbol = {...this.state.symbol}
        newSymbol[event.target.name] = event.target.value
        this.setState({
            symbol: newSymbol
        })
    }

    onSubmitSymbol = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.get(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=${this.state.symbol.enteredSymbol}&token=bq3klmvrh5rb0pdpe5ng`).then((response)=>{
            const current = response.data.c;
            const high = response.data.h;
            const low = response.data.l;
            const open = response.data.o;
            const close = response.data.pc;
            const timeStamp = response.data.t;


            this.setState({
                currentPrice: current,
                highPrice: high,
                lowPrice: low,
                openPrice: open,
                closePrice: close,
                time: timeStamp,
            })

            return axios.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=bq3klmvrh5rb0pdpe5ng')
        }).then((name)=>{
            const newName = name.data;
            for(let i = 0; i < newName.length; i++){
                if ( newName[i].displaySymbol === this.state.symbol.enteredSymbol){
                    this.setState({

                        stockName: newName[i].description

                    })

                }



            }
        })
    }

    //end of api calls for getting stock information

    //start of buying stocks for the user account

    buyStock = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault()
        axios.get(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=${this.state.symbol.enteredSymbol}&token=bq3klmvrh5rb0pdpe5ng`).then((response)=>{

            let current = parseInt(response.data.c);

            let balance = parseInt(this.state.accountBalance);

            // const newStockShares = {...this.state.user.stockShares}
            if ( balance > current) {
                balance.push(current);
                this.setState({
                    newBalacne: current += balance,
                    stockShares: + 1,
                })

            } else {
                alert('you do not have enough moeny for a share in this stock');
            }


        })

    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getUserInfo()
    }












    render() {
        return (
            <div>



                <ReactBootStrap.Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
    <ReactBootStrap.Navbar.Brand href="#home">The Stock App</ReactBootStrap.Navbar.Brand>
    <ReactBootStrap.Nav className="mr-auto">
      <ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link href="#home">Home</ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link>
      <ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link href="/resources">Resources</ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link>
      <ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link href="http://eoddata.com/symbols.aspx" target="_blank">Symbols</ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link>
      <ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link href="/account">My Account</ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link>
    </ReactBootStrap.Nav>
    <ReactBootStrap.Form onSubmit={this.onSubmitSymbol} inline>
      <ReactBootStrap.FormControl type="text" name="enteredSymbol" onChange={this.changeInput} placeholder="Enter Stock Symbol" className="mr-sm-2" />
      <ReactBootStrap.FormControl type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </ReactBootStrap.Form>
  </ReactBootStrap.Navbar>
  <br />


                <div>
                          <ReactBootStrap.Container>
  <ReactBootStrap.Row>
    <ReactBootStrap.Col>
        <ReactBootStrap.Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>

                            <ReactBootStrap.Card.Body>
                                <ReactBootStrap.Card.Title>{this.state.stockName}</ReactBootStrap.Card.Title>
                                </ReactBootStrap.Card.Body>
                                    <ReactBootStrap.ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
                                        <ReactBootStrap.ListGroupItem >Current price: { this.state.currentPrice}</ReactBootStrap.ListGroupItem>
                                        <ReactBootStrap.ListGroupItem>Low price: { this.state.lowPrice}</ReactBootStrap.ListGroupItem>
                                        <ReactBootStrap.ListGroupItem>High price: { this.state.highPrice}</ReactBootStrap.ListGroupItem>
                                    </ReactBootStrap.ListGroup>
                                    <ReactBootStrap.Card.Body>
                                    <ReactBootStrap.Button onClick={ this.buyStock } variant="dark">Buy Share</ReactBootStrap.Button>
                                {/* <ReactBootStrap.Card.Link href="#">Another Link</ReactBootStrap.Card.Link> */}
                                </ReactBootStrap.Card.Body>
                            </ReactBootStrap.Card>
                        </ReactBootStrap.Col>
    <ReactBootStrap.Col> 
        <ReactBootStrap.Card className="circle">
                                       <ReactBootStrap.Card.Title>User: ${ this.state.accountBalance }</ReactBootStrap.Card.Title>
                                       <ReactBootStrap.Card.Title>shares: { this.state.stockShares }</ReactBootStrap.Card.Title>
                                     </ReactBootStrap.Card>
                                     </ReactBootStrap.Col>
                            </ReactBootStrap.Row>
            </ReactBootStrap.Container>

                    <div>




                                    {/* <h2> {this.state.stockName}</h2>
                                     <p>Current price: { this.state.currentPrice}</p>
                                <p>Low price:{this.state.lowPrice}</p>
                                    <p> High price: {this.state.highPrice}</p> */}



                    </div>


                </div>





            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a lot of extraneous code in there, but the thing that jumped out was your `getUserInfo` function.  Instead of overwriting the entire `this.state.user` object, persist the previous and overwrite only what you want to change -

```
getUserInfo = () => {
  axios.get('/api/user').then((response) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      user: {
        ...prevState.user,
        accountBalance: response.data.accountBalance,
      }
    }))
  })
}
```

Comment: I understand i have a lot of code in this specific component that  I don't need or doesn't make sense but I do have a user component where if this makes sense i want to import that account balance from that component an the user data and import be able to store information from the rendered stock, but in notice in the components in my developer tools the objects are anonymous ```{ this.state.stockShares }``` , ```{this.state.accountBalance}```